# How to receive and pass value from <select> tag in React?

Tags: reactjs

Hey I need to pass value from selected option to `setAgeAnswer()`, which updates my state.

```
<select onChange={() =>setAgeAnswer(/*value of a selected option*/) }>
  {AgeList.map(element => (
    <option key={element} value={element}>
      {element}
    </option>
  ))}
```

I don't have an idea how to do it, I tried this:

```
const getValue = (object, callback) => {
   callback(object.value);
};

<select onChange={() => getValue(this, setAgeAnswer)}>
```

But `this` is undefined in this scope.

Comment: It seems you may have a lack of basics when it comes to React. Understanding props, and the **limitations** of __this__ in React/JS are vital to creating WAPPs.

Comment: @Dylan You're right. I definitely need to examine it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the `onChange` event receives the event as an argument and you can use this to obtain the value that was selected e.g. `event.target.value`.

Secondly, in React when using a `<select>`, set the `value` on the actual `<select>` element.

```
<select value={this.state.yourValue} onChange={(event) =>setAgeAnswer(event.target.value) }>
```

Comment: Thanks @MrCode, it works. Honestly I wouldn't even think of it

Answer (score 1):

First parameter of event handler is event object. it contains target which is DOM element which triggered the event. So you just need to get current value of it

```
<select onChange={(e) => setAgeAnswer(e.target.value) }>
  {AgeList.map(element => (
    <option key={element} value={element}>
      {element}
    </option>
  ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
onChange={(value)=>setAgeAnswer(value)}
```